# Finding an argument of a complex number using $\log$ function

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, power-series

> The argument of a complex number $z$ can be defined to be the
> imaginary part of $\log(z)$, where $\log$ function is defined as: Over the disc $\{1+z, |z|<1\}$, $\log(z)$ is defined by the power
> series
>
> $$\log(z)=(z-1)-\frac{(z-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(z-1)^3}{3}-\cdots$$

Given a complex number $z=a+ib$, we can find the magnitude $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and its argument as $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$. We need to be careful when calculating the argument. From my understanding, we always need to fix the region like $(-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi)$.

I found this alternative definition on how to find an argument of a complex number. Can anybody please explain how does it work?

Comment: @janmarqz thanks for your edit, I also think that it must be $\frac{(z-1)^3}{3}$, but in the original source it was $\frac{(z-1)^3}{2}$

Comment: which wasn't correct